# Cant access my docker containerized app via localhost

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile

Here is my docker file

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 as build-env
WORKDIR /src
COPY *.sln .

COPY */*.csproj .
RUN for file in $(ls *.csproj); do mkdir -p ${file%.*}/ && mv $file ${file%.*}/; done

RUN dotnet restore
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /publish

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 as runtime
WORKDIR /publish
COPY --from=build-env /publish .
EXPOSE 7000
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ToDoList.WebUI.dll"]
```

And the command I run my image with

```
docker run -p 7000:7000 todolist-app 
-e TodoListDefaultConnection="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=ToDoListDb;Integrated Security=True;TrustServerCertificate=True"
-e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
-e ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORT=https://+:7000
-e ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:7000
```

As you can see I'm trying to run my application on port 7000 but whenever I run the container I keep getting this message

> Now listening on: http://[::]:80

I am new to docker and have no clew what is the reason for this actually.

Comment: You have the various `-e` options _after_ the image name `todolist-app`, so they're interpreted as the command to run (your application probably will see them as arguments to its main function).  Do you need to move these options _before_ the image name, so they set environment variables for the container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Docker document, you must put options ( in this case `-e`) of the run command **before** the image name.

`docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]`

If you put the option after the image name, Docker does not know what you are inputting to it.

See [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#options) for more details on it.